# Ошибка в php 7.1 при загрузке изображения на сервер

Tags: php, изображения, загрузка

Выдает ошибку:

> Only variables should be passed by reference

Ругается на строку где получаем расширение:

```
$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['picture']['name']));
```

И только на php 5.3 работает нормально

Сам код:

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {

$path = 'i/';

$ext = array_pop(explode('.',$_FILES['picture']['name'])); 

$new_name = time().'.'.$ext; 

$full_path = $path.$new_name;

if($_FILES['picture']['error'] == 0){

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $full_path)){

}
}
else{

echo "Ошибка";
}
```

как убрать эту ошибку на php 7.1 ?

Answer (score 4):

Тоже натыкался на такое при переходе на PHP7+, проблема в том что нужно вынести результат `explode` в отдельную переменную:

```
$name = explode('.',$_FILES['picture']['name']);
$ext = array_pop($name);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, добрый человек!

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что функция `array_pop` в качестве аргумента принимает ссылку на массив. В PHP7 внесено много изменений в [механизм передачи по ссылке](http://php.net/manual/ru/migration70.incompatible.php) и, в частности, попытка передать по ссылке результат выполнения функции теперь вызывает ошибку.

Соответственно, как правильно сказал Ярослав, делать нужно так:

```
$name = explode('.',$_FILES['picture']['name']);
$ext = array_pop($name);
```

Comment: и вам спасибо!)